# Why foreach not working with date changer?

Tags: php

I want to change my database dates from jalali to gregorian. but when I run the code, foreach not working and not getting all of my datas from database.
This is my code in my php file:

```
$sqlslct = "SELECT * FROM numberslist1";
$resslct = $connect->query($sqlslct);
foreach($resslct as $rsslct) {
    $datee = $rsslct['datee'];
    $dateeex = explode("-", $datee);
    function div($a,$b) { 
        return (int) ($a / $b); 
    }
    function jalali_to_gregorian($j_y, $j_m, $j_d,$str) {

        $g_days_in_month = array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31); 
        $j_days_in_month = array(31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 29); 
 
 
        $jy = (int)($j_y)-979; 
        $jm = (int)($j_m)-1; 
        $jd = (int)($j_d)-1; 
 
        $j_day_no = 365*$jy + div($jy, 33)*8 + div($jy%33+3, 4); 
   
        for ($i=0; $i < $jm; ++$i) 
            $j_day_no += $j_days_in_month[$i]; 
 
            $j_day_no += $jd; 
 
            $g_day_no = $j_day_no+79; 
 
            $gy = 1600 + 400*div($g_day_no, 146097); /* 146097 = 365*400 + 400/4 - 400/100 + 400/400 */ 
            $g_day_no = $g_day_no % 146097; 
 
        $leap = true; 
        if ($g_day_no >= 36525) /* 36525 = 365*100 + 100/4 */ 
        { 
            $g_day_no--; 
            $gy += 100*div($g_day_no,  36524); /* 36524 = 365*100 + 100/4 - 100/100 */ 
            $g_day_no = $g_day_no % 36524; 
 
        if ($g_day_no >= 365) 
            $g_day_no++; 
        else 
            $leap = false; 
        } 
 
        $gy += 4*div($g_day_no, 1461); /* 1461 = 365*4 + 4/4 */ 
        $g_day_no %= 1461; 
 
        if ($g_day_no >= 366) { 
            $leap = false; 
 
            $g_day_no--; 
            $gy += div($g_day_no, 365); 
            $g_day_no = $g_day_no % 365; 
        } 
 
        for ($i = 0; $g_day_no >= $g_days_in_month[$i] + ($i == 1 && $leap); $i++) 
            $g_day_no -= $g_days_in_month[$i] + ($i == 1 && $leap); 
            $gm = $i+1; 
            $gd = $g_day_no+1; 
        if($str) return $gy.'/'.$gm.'/'.$gd ;
            return array($gy, $gm, $gd); 
    } 
    $str = true;
    $datee2 = jalali_to_gregorian($dateeex[0], $dateeex[1], $dateeex[2],$str);
    $datee1 = explode("/", $datee2);
    $datee4 = jalali_to_gregorian($dateeex[0], $dateeex[1], $dateeex[2],$str);
    $datee3 = str_replace("/", "-", $datee4);
    $month = $datee1[1];
    $year = $datee1[0];
    echo $datee3." / ".$month." / ".$year."<br>";
}
```

This code should print a tall result of dates from my database in the page, like this example:

```
2022-2-9 / 2 / 2022
2022-2-10 / 2 / 2022
2022-2-11 / 2 / 2022
2022-2-12 / 2 / 2022
2022-2-13 / 2 / 2022
2022-2-14 / 2 / 2022
And more...
```

But it will show just one date in the page. why is this happen? is there any problem with date changer? because I tested the code without `jalali_to_gregorian()` function and the result was correct.

Comment: Why you have added `jalali_to_gregorian` insider the loop? It should be out of the loop

Comment: @Rikesh oh yes, that was the problem... thanks bro.